# beginner - solve a simple convex optimisation

Tags: mathematical-optimization, tensorflow

I am a beginner at Tensorflow. I took the line-fit example from the "getting started" page, 
and made what I thought is a nearly trivial modification to it, but it fails completely.
I do not understand.

In the modified version, an array b_data is a sum of two known Gaussians, with unknown weights.
Try to solve for those weights.  This is a quadratic problem that can be solved
as a linear system.

Although the true weights are 0.4, 0.2,  the gradient descent gives w[0] negative,
and w[1] positive.

That is the issue: **although the problem is convex (quadratic even), tensorflow does not find the right answer.**

I think I must be doing something wrong with the loss function?
In fact I think using a loss

`tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(b - b_data))`

is what I want (corresponding to the squared 2-norm || b - b_data ||^2),
however trying this is even worse, it results in NaNs.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import tensorflow as tf

RES = 200
CEN = [0.2, 0.3, 0.6]
SD = [0.1, 0.15, 0.07]
X = np.linspace(0., 1., RES).astype(np.float32)
G0 = np.exp( - np.power(X - CEN[0], 2) / SD[0])
G1 = np.exp( - np.power(X - CEN[1], 2) / SD[1])
B = np.vstack([G0,G1])
B = B.T

b_data = 0.4*G0 + 0.2*G1 

# check numpy answer
w_ = np.linalg.lstsq(B,b_data)
print('numpy answer',w_[0])       # correct: 0.4, 0.2

w = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2,1], 0., 0.5))
b = tf.matmul(B,w)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(b - b_data))
#loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(b - b_data))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for step in xrange(8001):
    sess.run(train)
    if step % 100 == 0:
        print(step, sess.run(loss), sess.run(tf.transpose(w)))

print('w', sess.run(w))
bfit = sess.run(w[0,0])*G0 + sess.run(w[1,0])*G1 

pl.clf()
pl.plot(G0,'g-')
pl.plot(G1,'b-')
pl.plot(b_data,'r-')
pl.plot(bfit,'k-')
pl.show()
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you get? Or is it just that print(step, sess.run(loss), sess.run(tf.transpose(w)))
returns NaN?

Comment: I added a clarification. The issue is that the tensor flow code does not find the correct solution.

Comment: I tried printing gradient and it goes to zero fast so I thought it's a local minimum. `[wgrad,_] = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, [w])[0]` But the problem seems quadratic so that's weird

Answer (score 0):

You are not optimizing the right cost function but a larger one as the substraction broadcast your arrays `b_data` and `b` :

```
> print(tf.square(b - b_data))
Tensor("Square:0", shape=(200, 200), dtype=float32)

>print(tf.square(b[:, 0] - b_data))
Tensor("Square:0", shape=(200,), dtype=float32)
```

This is caused by a counter intuitive broadcast in the tensorflow implementation [(see for instance this issue)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1406).

If you replace your loss with `loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(b[:, 0] - b_data))`, the optimization succeeds and gives back the result.